# Correct implementation of std::streambuf::overflow

Tags: c++, iostream

I am creating a special std::streambuf and std::ostream implementation. For that I need to implement the `std::streambuf::overflow` function. The function is protected, only called by `std::streambuf::sputc` and `std::streambuf::xsputn` and only when there is no more room in the buffer (that is `pptr() == epptr()`). The default behaviour is to return `eof`, so it is obviously not correct to call the function in place of `sputc`.

Nevertheless both GNU libc implementation of `std::stringbuf` and boost implementation of `boost::io::alt_stringbuf` in Boost.Format still check whether `pptr() < epptr()` and such case simply append the character. In the later case even daringly by calling `sputc` (and thus relying on the fact that it will not call `overflow` if there is still room in the buffer).

What is the reason to implement this case?

Ok, I don't really understand the other case, `overflow(eof())`, either. It does not appear to be actually used anywhere though it is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question seems to be why implementation check if `this->pptr() == this->epptr()`: the simple reason is that a further derived class might end up calling the `protected` function! The standard C++ library will never call `overflow()` when there is space in the buffer. For some time I used to also check whether `this->pptr() == this->epptr()` but I have stopped doing so: the implicit contract is that further derived class don't do silly things.

The other question raised is: what does it mean for `overflow()` to be called with the argument `traits_type::eof()`? Although I keep handling this case it is another case which doesn't happen from within the standard C++ library: the intention is to have `overflow()` flush the stream. That is, `sync()` would just call `this->overflow(traits_type::eof())`. In practise I found it more reasonable to call `sync()` from `overflow()` probably after storing the character into the buffer (i.e., `sync()` woube called with `pptr() == epptr() + 1` which, of course, assumes that the allocated buffer has space for at least one more character).